# Find the number of different complex solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

There is given matrix $A$, where z is a complex number. Find how many different complex number there is, that $\det(A^{4}) = 16$.

$A =\begin{bmatrix}
z & z+1 & 1\\
1 & z & z+1 \\
z+1 & 1 & z
\end{bmatrix}$

I have calculated that $det(A^4)$ is equal to $(z(z+2)(z-\frac{1}{2}))^4$. And there are four roots of $16$, $2, -2, 2i, -2i$. So let the $p(z)=z(z+2)(z-\frac{1}{2})$. How can I tell how many different roots have polynomials $p(z) - 2 = 0,p(z) + 2 = 0,p(z) - 2i = 0,p(z) + 2i = 0$?

Comment: Standard determinant

Comment: The determinant of 3 x 3 Matrice.

Comment: Actually $\det(A) = 2 z^3 + 2$, not $z (z+2)(z-1/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\det(A^4)=16$ if and only if
$$
0=16z^{12} + 64z^9 + 96z^6 + 64z^3=16z^3(z^6 + 2z^3 + 2)(z^3 + 2).
$$
So we only have to count the number of complex roots from here. So we have $12$ complex roots. Note that $\det(A^4)=\det(A)^4$.

Comment: We don't need to **find** the roots, just count them.  And don't forget the other factors.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, thank you. But this is even easier.